# MySQL information_schema.columns extra column options

Tags: mysql, schema

I didn't found any documentation about. What is the possible options for the information_schema.columns table `extra` column. Currently I just get *auto_increment*. I just building a migrater and I want to cover every possibilites.

The SQL query which get it:

```
SELECT EXTRA
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the full list of possible values for that column is not documented for [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html), you can find it on the manual page for [SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html):

> The Extra field contains any additional information that is available about a given column. The value is nonempty in these cases:
>
> - auto_increment for columns that have the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute
> - on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for TIMESTAMP or DATETIME columns that have the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute
> - VIRTUAL GENERATED or STORED GENERATED for generated columns

Note that the `VIRTUAL GENERATED` and `STORED GENERATED` values are new in MySQL 5.7, and it's possible that more values will be added in MySQL 8.0 and beyond.

Comment: Thank you, then this is why I didn't found the documentation.